# Setting mail server in wso2 identity server 5.3

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am getting crazy in setting email server for password recovery.

I have followed password recovery guide [1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Password+Recovery).
When I try to recover the password the GUI informs me that the email has been sent correctly but on the logs I find the following exception:

```
[2017-03-08 09:24:42,913] ERROR -  Event dropped at Output Adapter 'EmailPublish
er' for tenant id '-1234', Error in message format, null {org.wso2.carbon.event.
output.adapter.email.EmailEventAdapter}
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.email.EmailEventAdapter$EmailSen
der.run(EmailEventAdapter.java:306)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have done many temptatives. I have included in wso2is-5.3.0\repository\conf\axis2.xml a configuration for gmail. Then I have tried with a configuration for our enterpise server. Finally I wrote a java program to check eventual network configuration problems and I was able to send email both with gmail and with our internal email server.
Please find here the two configurations that I tried:
GMAIL

```
 <transportSender name="mailto"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender">
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.from">********@gmail.com</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.user">********</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.password">********</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.host">smtp.gmail.com</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.port">587</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.auth">true</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

I have already set in gmail the security setting related to accept "less secure clients" and I am able to exploit the gmail account with another framework (jasper report).

Enterprise Email Server

```
<transportSender name="mailto"
                     class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender">
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.from">*********</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.user">********</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.password">*********</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.host">mailer.******.it</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.port">25</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.auth">true</parameter>
    </transportSender>
```

Thanks in advance..
- Giovanni (A poor developer :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to enable WSO2IS to send recovery password email in response to the the user actions on the dashboard ("forgot password" link on the login page) the file to edit with the mail server parameter is output-event-adapters.xml inside the repository/conf folder.

Comment: Hi, maybe you know how to send a letter in WSO2 using other locale (language)?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC I solved same issue by adding same mail config to axis2_client.xml as well inside same section. Hope that helps. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "same section" ?

Comment: Please could you expand you answer?

Answer (score 0):

From WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 onwards, In order to send emails, We need to update the output-event-adapters.xml file located in wso2is-5.3.0/repository/conf directory as below. Once you update it and when you have configured the Gmail account to accept less secure clients, It should work

```
<adapterConfig type="email">
    <!-- Comment mail.smtp.user and mail.smtp.password properties to support connecting SMTP servers which use trust
    based authentication rather username/password authentication -->
    <property key="mail.smtp.from">abcd@gmail.com</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.user">abcd</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.password">xxxx</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.host">smtp.gmail.com</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.port">587</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.auth">true</property>
    <!-- Thread Pool Related Properties -->
    <property key="minThread">8</property>
    <property key="maxThread">100</property>
    <property key="keepAliveTimeInMillis">20000</property>
    <property key="jobQueueSize">10000</property>
</adapterConfig>
```

Comment: Hi, Even after adding Adapter config, I am getting the same issue. Can you please provide some guidance? The same config works on ESB with axis2 mailto transport but not in Identity server.

Comment: The same adapterConfig file is working well in different environment though

Answer (score 0):

In webfaction with this configuration it works, using the smtp of webfaction:

conf/axis2/axis2.xml

```
<transportSender name="mailto"
                 class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender">
    <parameter name="mail.from">xxxx@xxx.com</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.from">xxxx@xxx.com</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.submitter">xxxx@xxx.com</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.user">yyyy</parameter>
    <parameter name="password">zzzzzz</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.host">smtp.webfaction.com</parameter>

    <parameter name="mail.smtp.port">25</parameter>
    <parameter name="mail.smtp.auth">true</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

conf/output-event-adapters.xml

```
<adapterConfig type="email">
    <!-- Comment mail.smtp.user and mail.smtp.password properties to support connecting SMTP servers which use trust
    based authentication rather username/password authentication -->
    <property key="mail.from">xxxx@xxx.com</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.from">xxxx@xxx.com</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.submitter">xxxx@xxx.com</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.user">yyyy</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.password">zzzzz</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.host">smtp.webfaction.com</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.port">25</property>
    <property key="mail.smtp.auth">true</property>
    <property key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</property>
    <!-- Thread Pool Related Properties -->
    <property key="minThread">8</property>
    <property key="maxThread">100</property>
    <property key="keepAliveTimeInMillis">20000</property>
    <property key="jobQueueSize">10000</property>
</adapterConfig>
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by

1. Turn on less secure app to use Gmail in Gmail accout
2. make sure the user name and from address you use for `SMTP` config in `WSO2IS` is same 1:e.,

   `<parameter name="mail.smtp.from">xyz@gmail.com</parameter>`

   `<parameter name="mail.smtp.user">xyz@gmail.com</parameter>`